# Magento 2 Create Product Details pdf?

Tags: product, magento-2.1, pdf, list.phtml, download-link

How can I create a pdf file with Product details and download it by clicking on download image in product list page in magento 2.Can anybody Help me on this.

Comment: Do you want to download as per category?

Answer (score 0):

Action will be pass in html form as below :

```
<form id="download_product" method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/foldername/action')?>">
```

Then below code you can add into your controller:

```
namespace vendor\modulename\Controller\foldername;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class actionname extends Action
{

protected $mycustomblock;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \vendor\modulename\Block\Mycustomblock $mycustomblock,
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->mycustomblock = $mycustomblock;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);   
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $categoryId = $params['category'];//Here i am passing category id from my form or you can get current category id if you are in a listing page

        $heading = array('Name','Id','Sku','Qty','Availability'); //here you can add details as per your requirement

        $outputFile = "products_". date('Ymd_His').".csv";
        $handle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
        fputcsv($handle, $heading);

        //fputcsv($fp, $header);
         foreach($categoryId as $key => $id ) 
        { 
        $categoryProducts = $this->mycustomblock->getProductCollection($id); you can get product collection

                foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {
                    $output=array();                  
                    $productStock = $this->mycustomblock->getStockItem($product->getId());

                    $output[]= $product->getName();
                    $output[]= $product->getId();
                    $output[]= $product->getSku();
                    if($productStock){
                    $output[]= $productStock->getQty();
                    $output[]= $productStock->getIsInStock();
                    }                   
                    fputcsv($handle, $output); 
                }

        }

        $this->downloadCsv($outputFile);

        unlink($outputFile);
        if (!unlink($file))
          {
          echo ("Error deleting $file");
          }
        else
          {
          echo ("Deleted $file");
          }

        //return $this;

    }

    public function downloadCsv($file){
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            //set appropriate headers
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
            ob_clean();flush();
            readfile($file);
        } 
    }

}
```

Let me know if you will need more help!